# Why does `stack --version` seem to show a different version than was installed?

Tags: linux, bash, haskell, haskell-stack

I ran `stack upgrade` and it seems to have worked. Output to the console says I have a new stack executable, but `stack --version` says differently. What am I missing?

```
~
$ stack upgrade
Current Stack version: 1.3.2, available download version: 1.7.1
Newer version detected, downloading
Querying for archive location for platform: osx-x86_64-static
Querying for archive location for platform: osx-x86_64
Downloading from: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/releases/download/v1.7.1/stack-1.7.1-osx-x86_64.tar.gz
Download complete, testing executable
Version 1.7.1, Git revision 681c800873816c022739ca7ed14755e85a579565 (5807 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.28.2
New stack executable available at /Users/skissh/.local/bin/stack
~
$ which stack
/Users/skissh/.local/bin/stack
~
$ stack --version
Version 1.3.2, Git revision 3f675146590da4f3edf768b89355f798229da2a5 (4395 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.15.0
~
$ cd ~/.local/bin
~/.local/bin
$ ls -l
total 64040
-rwxr-xr-x  1 skissh  staff  32788156 Jun 17 12:27 stack
~/.local/bin
```

Comment: Does `hash -r` fix the issue?

Comment: I went to lookup hash and inadvertently closed terminal. In a new terminal I ran `stack --version` and the updated version, 1.7.1, was reported. I'm new to bash, is that a thing, not knowing the current state unless restarted? Thanks for the help Thomas. Should I leave it at that, answer my own question, or edit it?

Comment: [How do I clear Bash's cache of paths to executables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5609/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Does Bash have cache of executables?](https://superuser.com/q/871854/173513) on [Super User](http://superuser.com/), etc.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question, that's entirely legitimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Thomas M. DuBuisson commented this could well have been fixable with `hash -r`. After restarting terminal the newly installed executable was referenced by `stack --version`. I didn't run `hash -r`, but I did run `hash` in the new terminal and the cache had been cleared.